# Tomcat connection pool, connection timeout

Tags: tomcat7, connection-pooling

I have an application running on tomcat 7.0.65, and using `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`

I have connection pool setup:

```java
PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
    p.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@....");
    p.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    p.setUsername("***");
    p.setPassword("***");
    p.setJmxEnabled(true);
    p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
    p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1 from dual");
    p.setTestOnReturn(false);
    p.setValidationInterval(30000);
    p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
    p.setMaxActive(100);
    p.setInitialSize(10);
    p.setMaxWait(10000);
    p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
    p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
    p.setMinIdle(10);
    p.setLogAbandoned(true);
    p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    p.setName("jdbc/insurancePool");
    DataSource asyncDS = new DataSource(p);
```

Everyday when I try to run the application I get connection timed out exception for the first couple of tries. I am not sure why this is happening. Does firewall have anything to do with this?

Comment: What's DataSource? what connection pool are you using?

Comment: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource

Comment: Try to add setIgnoreExceptionOnPreLoad(false); and add stack trace to question

Comment: I have made the changes, once i get the stack trace will add it here.. I get these exceptions at the start of the day..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with MySql everyday morning. Then I found autoReconnect parameter which can be used with JDBC URL to fix this.

For example:

```
MYSQL_URL=jdbc:mysql://10.*.*.0:3306/ABC?autoReconnect=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved, found this link helpful [Firewall Issues](https://vivekagarwal.wordpress.com/2009/07/04/firewall-dropping-oracle-database-connections-in-websphere-connection-pool/)

I changed "minIdle" to 0 and also set sqlnet.expire_time parameter in the sqlnet.ora file to 0..

Hope this helps someone else..